# jQuery jPlayer Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting the following error. I am using HTML5. I am trying to add an audio file. The error is:

Unable to get value of the property 'jPlayer': object is null or undefined

It is throwing an error on the

This is my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jpId").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    this.element.jPlayer("setFile", "../179_short_all-the-family-together_0033.mp3"); // Defines the counterpart mp3 and ogg files
                },
                oggSupport: true,

            });
        });
```

My HTML5 div:

```
<div id="jpId">
</div>
```

I have tried using the  tag but I need the music to work in IE8, IE9, Firefox, Chrome. I know I need to add .ogg file but wanted to get it working before adding other file types. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! In order to get the best results from a javascript question, I suggest creating a JSfiddle. You can do so here... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: have you tried to debug it to see if it actually finds the $("jpId") object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check the jPlayer Demo code and document first. (http://www.jplayer.org)

And I think you have to change your js like this:

```
$('#jpId').jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { //use "setMedia". "setFile" doesn't in DevGuide
            mp3: "class.mp3", //set mp3 media path, also can use url
            oga: "pop.ogg" // set ogg media path, pay attention to use "oga" not "ogg"
        });
    },
    preload: "none",
    supplied: "oga, mp3", //test set the order of media you want to use
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jpContainer" // in order to add the controller
});
```

Html code suggestion:

```
<div id="jpId"></div>
<div id="jpContainer">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a>
 </div>
```

you can check the DEMO page I wrote:

 http://ohcool.org/sof/13628641.html

if you want to know more about browser music file type support, check:

 http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Good luck!